# Functions of modulus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How do I calculate the range of any modulus function?  I know that if $x <2$ then it's expansion is negative and if $x>2$, it's expansion is negative, but will it help? Consider an example,  $$f (x)=\frac{|x-2|}{x+2}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We handle the modulus (absolute value sign), by splitting the function into two cases: $x<2$ and $x\ge 2$. The $x+2$ in the denominator means we also need to look at $x$ less-than and greater-than $-2$. So we look at three cases.

**Case 1: $x<-2$**

Here $|x-2|=-(x-2)=2-x$ so

$$f(x)=\frac{2-x}{x+2}=\frac 4{x+2}-1$$

As $x$ approaches $\infty$, $f(x)$ approaches $0-1=-1$ without reaching it. As $x$ approaches $-2$ from the left, $f(x)$ approaches $-\infty$. So the range here is $(-\infty,-1)$.

**Case 2: $-2<x<2$**

Here again $|x-2|=2-x$ so $f(x)=\frac 4{x+2}-1$. As $x$ approaches $-2$ from the right, $f(x)$ approaches $+\infty$. As $x$ approaches $2$ from the left, $f(x)$ approaches $0$ without reaching it. So the range here is $(0,+\infty)$.

**Case 3: $2\le x$**

Here $|x-2|=x-2$, so

$$f(x)=\frac{x-2}{x+2}=1-\frac 4{x+2}$$

As $x$ approaches $2$ from the right and reaches it, $f(x)$ approaches and reaches $0$. As $x$ approaches $+\infty$, $f(x)$ approaches $1$ without reaching it. So the range here is $[0,1)$.

Our final range is the union of those three sub-ranges, namely

> $$(-\infty,-1)\cup[0,+\infty)$$

Note that the interval $[-1,0)$ is left out of the range. This is because the modulus "bent" the graph of the hyperbola at $x=2$. Without that, the graph would have been a typical hyperbola missing only one value, $-1$, in its range.

We can easily check all this with a graph.

[image]

Again, we handled the modulus by considering two cases. The denominator split one of those cases into two sub-cases, so we looked at three cases overall.